# Laravel migration fails on Ubuntu server but not on wamp

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, ubuntu

I have been working on a project and have finally hit the point where it is ready to be deployed on the ubuntu server, I have been working with WAMP on a windows machine to do development and everything runs smooth.

The issue is when I try to migrate the database on the ubuntu server I get the following error.

```
 SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `app_servers` add constraint `app_servers_app_id_foreign` foreign key (`app_id`) references `app` (`id`))
```

I have never deployed a site to a production server before so I am a little lost on how I could get this error on Ubuntu but not on WAMP migrations?

I believe my migrations are collect because they do run on the local machine on WAMP. Attached at bottom is screenshot of migration order.

Can anyone help lead me in the right direction of a solution for this issue? Posted below is a link to the article I have been using to help me attempt to deploy this. I looked at some of the questions already asked on here but none of which address the issue I am having.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-laravel-application-with-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04

[image]